# Error 0: No Error while using JavaScript for Automation in Evernote

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, evernote

I'm creating a Script for turning Evernote Notes into Omnifocus-Items, using Javascript for Automation. Currently, the script searches for items with a certain tag, which works great. Now, I want to unassign this tag or assign a different tag to ensure no Note gets added twice.

Looking into the Evernote Javascript for Automation Function Library in the Script Editor, I found the methods assign / unassign, which should do what I want - but I'm unable to use them.

This is a shortened version of my code:

```
Evernote = Application('Evernote');
var notes = Evernote.findNotes("tag:omni");

for(i = 0, len = notes.length; i < len; i++){
    var note = notes[i];
    // Add Tag inOmni
    var tag = Evernote.Tag({name:'inOmni'});
    Evernote.assign(tag, {to: note});
}
```

This gives me the ultra-useful error message `Error 0: No error`. I tried `var tag = Evernote.Tag({name:'inOmni'}).make();` (using make()), which results in the script editor reminding me the tag "inOmni" already exists.

It seems like I need to get the actual Tag-Object for 'inOmni', but how can I do this?

Also, is there any documentation or sample code for Evernote JavaScript Automation?

I already asked this on Ask Different, but it didn't get any answers.

Comment: JXA's a broken obfuscated mess. I don't have Evernote but I'm guessing you misunderstand how to use tags. I recommend you work out how to do it right in AppleScript, then post that code if you still can't figure out how it translates to JS. (Or, y'know, just stick with AS which, unlike JXA, actually works right and has plenty of experienced users who can help you out.)

Comment: Evernote's Apple Script documentation: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/applescript.php

Comment: @pybolt I did search for a working Applescript, but it turns out that assigning/unassigning tags in Evernote using AppleScript / JS is currently broken (see [here](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/51212-applescript-to-add-tags/). If it were not, it would look like `assign tag "receipt" to note`, which should translate to `Evernote.assign("tag", {to: note})`, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is kinda stale… but still here's the code for creating an evernote.tag instance:

```
new_tag ​​= Application('Evernote').make({
        new:'tag', 
        withProperties:{name: 'new tag name'}
        })
```

All credit goes to E_Mattsan who wrote this blog post:
https://blog.emattsan.org/entry/20150926/1443270834